# How Null values are programmatically implemented in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, null

How the database solved the problem of NULL values in mysql db? E.g In C, null is implemented as #define NULL '\0'

Comment: It’s a flag. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

In general, databases implement `NULL` values by having a separate flag column for each nullable column.

The flag is "hidden" in the sense that it is not accessed directly.  Instead, the engine understands how and when to reference the flag.

`NULL` is -- in general -- not implemented as a "special" value.